# How to parse enum logical sum?

Tags: c#, enums

Say, we have a font:

```
        Font f = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic | FontStyle.Bold);
```

How to go through its styles?

```
        foreach (FontStyle style in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontStyle))
                                        .OfType<FontStyle>()
                                        .Where(fs => f.Style.HasFlag(fs)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(style);
        }
```

This is one way. But

1. It returns `FontStyle.Regular` as well. Why?
2. Is there a better way to do the task?

Comment: Why do you want each style?  If you just want to print it I suggest `style.ToString("F")`.  If you need to do something with each style in the list then update your where statement to `.Where(fs => fs != FontStyle.Regular && f.Style.HasFlag(fs)))`

Comment: @Trisped I'm making a custom font editor, I want to have a CheckedListBox to edit font style. Depending on `Font` instance, it'll check the necessary items. So I need to extract the values from `font.Style`.

Comment: Sorry, tried to delete comment, but my computer crashed (does not like to wake up from hibernate).  Please see my suggested answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FontStyle.Regular == 0`. So it will be always "present" in value of this enumeration type because anything `&` 0 (binary and) is 0.

```
value &  FontStyle.Regular == FontStyle.Regular
```

Depending on your needs you can explcitly ignore 0 values of `Flags` enumerations or do explicit `if` for styles.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs for the `HasFlag` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) :

> If the underlying value of flag is zero, the method returns true. If
>   this behavior is not desirable, you can use the Equals method to test
>   for equality with zero and call HasFlag only if the underlying value
>   of flag is non-zero

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want each style?  If you just want to print it I suggest `style.ToString("F")`.

The [FontStyle enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx) is short enough that I would just program each case rather then using LINQ and reflection.  It is not likely that they will add another style resulting in this code needing to be updated.

```
if  (f.Style.HasFlag(FontStyle.Bold)) { Console.WriteLine(style); }
if  (f.Style.HasFlag(FontStyle.Italic)) { Console.WriteLine(style); }
if  (f.Style.HasFlag(FontStyle.Underline)) { Console.WriteLine(style); }
if  (f.Style.HasFlag(FontStyle.Strikeout)) { Console.WriteLine(style); }
```

Otherwise update your where statement:

```
.Where(fs => fs != FontStyle.Regular && f.Style.HasFlag(fs)))
```